# Does this set of coordinates result in a curve?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Coordinates: $(0,0), (3,3), (6,4.5), (9, 5.25)$

If this is a curve is there a formula for determining the $y$ value for any given $x$ within the range $0$ to $9?$

Comment: What type of curve are you talking about ?

Comment: Sadly there are many curves that pass through these four points, so it requires more information such as "cubic polynomial" to make a unique determination.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking at [Lagrange's Interpolation Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html). Given any $n$ points, they can always be interpolated by a polynomial of degree $n-1$ or less. This means that those points will always lie on the curve of that polynomial. So given your 4 points, there is a polynomial of degree 3 or less such that the points are on the curve of that polynomial. The explicit equation for the polynomial can be found using the formula included in the link.

However, these four points most definitely do not determine uniquely a continuous function (a curve). There are very many curves that could pass through these points.

Comment: I agree with Christian. This Lagrange interpolation formula will give you the polynomial $$f(x)=\dfrac{4}{3}x-\dfrac{1}{8}x^2+\dfrac{1}{216}x^3$$

Answer (score 0):

This particular curve can be also $f(x)=6(1-2^{-x/3})$. Here is how I guessed this function:

1. you go in steps of 3, so you might have something $x/3$.
2. At the first step the function increases by 3, then at the next step by 3/2, then 3/4. From here, I would guess that the formula is $$\sum_s3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^s,$$ where $s=x/3$
3. $\sum_s(1/2)^s=\frac{1-(1/2)^{s+1}}{1-1/2}$